# Run Linux guest on Windows 10 VMWare host with GPU

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I have a Linux guest (Ubuntu 18.04) running on Windows 10 host, VMWare Player 14.

Host has a NVidia GTX 960M.

Is it possible for the guest to leverage the GPU? (Either by using VMWare Player, or VMWare Workstation).

Comment: Yes, definitely. Running OpenGL in Ubuntu 16.04 guest on Window 10 Pro host, GTX 980m, VMware Workstation 12.5. What is the problem?

Comment: I don't see performance changes as compared to the native Intel graphics. I've been using the NVidia GPU Activity monitor, and it does not show any activity on VMWare host app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running OpenGL in Ubuntu 16.04 64bit guest on Window 10 Pro 64bit host, GTX 980m, VMware Workstation Pro 12.5.7, Intel I7-6820 cpu

There are several step how to do it

1. In the VMware setup for particular virtual machine enable 3D acceleration
   [image]
2. In Ubuntu guest install vm-open-tools (three packages)
3. Install xserver-xorg-video-vmware, xserver-xorg-video-vmmouse
4. Install mesa-utils

Then all things shall work seamlessly

How to check:

1. glxinfo | grep Vendor shall tell you that vendor is VMware
2. Run glxgears. With accelerated OpenGL you'll get circa 2000 FPS. With software rendered OpenGL you'll get probably around 200 FPS (depending on CPU)